# Login Failed Always

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web

Good day I am a newbie in webdev. Im trying to create a project where in there is a login form that users will input their username and password.Whenever the button is click it will display a message Login successfully and if the username and password is not stored in the xml it will display Login Failed!!.Can someone tell me what is the mistake of the code?Login keeps having alert message Login Failed when button is click.Below is the code.Thanks in advance for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frmlogin" name="frmlogin" method="post" action="Login" onsumbit="return false;">
            <p>ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" name="login_username" id="username"></p>
            <p> ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="login_pass" id="password"><br><br>
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Log in" onclick="login()">
            </p>

        </form>
        <script>            
            window.login = function(e)
            {

                if (document.frmlogin.login_username.value == "") 
                {
                    alert("User name is not blank");
                    return;
                }
                else if(document.frmlogin.login_pass.value == "")
                {
                    alert("Password is not blank");
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        myFunction(this);
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "user.xml", true);
                xhttp.send();
                }
                function myFunction(xml) {
                    var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

                    var ktra=true;
                    var xml=xmlDoc.childNodes[0].childNodes[1];

                    var name = xml.childNodes["username"];        
                    var pass=xml.childNodes["password"];
                    for(var i=0;i<xml.childNodes.length;i++){
                        if(xml.childNodes[i].nodeName="username")
                            name = xml.childNodes[i];
                        if(xml.childNodes[i].nodeName="password")
                            pass = xml.childNodes[i];
                    }
                    if(name.textContent==frmlogin.login_username.value &&pass.textContent==frmlogin.login_pass.value)
                    {
                        ktra=true;        

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ktra=false;
                    }

                    if(ktra==true)
                    {
                        alert("Login Successfully !!!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Login Failed !!!");
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is xml code

```
<users>
    <user>
        <username>A</username>
        <password>12345</password>
    </user>
</users>
```

Comment: You posted this once already. There is absolutely no reason to post the same identical question again. If your other question is not getting answers, it's because it's poorly written, and you should go back and edit it to improve it rather than just posting it again.

Comment: Are you testing locally or using a server?

Answer (score -2):

You need a space between the `&&` and the condition in your `if` check comparing the user and password.